# Azure B2C - Not able to read "Date" Claim from JWT client assertion token in policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm not able to read date claim from JWT client assertion token and then transform into "datetime" claim by transformation method "ConvertDateToDateTimeClaim". I've tried below date formats in claim but none works. It works as excepted, When I set Default values of Date claim in B2C policy.

JWT Token:
{
  "createdDate1": "2019-05-26",
  "createdDate2": "2019-05-26T00:00:00",
  "createdDate3": "2019-05-26T00:00:00Z",
  "verifiedEmail": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "nbf": 1560005928,
  "exp": 1560006228,
  "iss": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

Error: The data type 'String' of the claim with id 'createdDate' does not match the DataType 'Date' of ClaimType with id 'createdDate' specified in the policy.

[B2C Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJpx.png)

Help required.

Comment: Hi @Jeeva. What if the date claim is set to a [NumericDate](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-2), i.e. the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC to the created time UTC, like the `exp` claim?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Hi, I tried this with reading the claim from a JWT in the idTokenHint parameter. Did also not work. Have not found a way to read a dateTime correctly yet.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug trying to read a dateTime claim from the JWT in the id_token_hint parameter. It got fixed this week. I could imagine it is the same with a date claim.

I create a JWT with the following claim:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
new System.Security.Claims.Claim("LinkExpirationDateTime", ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_appSettings.LinkExpiresAfterMinutes) - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds).ToString(), System.Security.Claims.ClaimValueTypes.DateTime, issuer)
```

You can read it like shown in some samples on https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/ ("Email delivered account redemption link" for example). The ClaimType would be:

```
<ClaimType Id="LinkExpirationDateTime">
    <DisplayName>LinkExpirationDateTime</DisplayName>
    <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```